# Extracting an Interior Portion from a Tikz ClipPicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-pic, path-clipping, clip

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

% % COMPILED WITH PDFLATEX

    \newif\ifdeveloppath
    \tikzset{/tikz/develop clipping path/.is if=developpath,
      /tikz/develop clipping path=true}

    \newcommand{\clippicture}[2]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \ifdeveloppath
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\phantom{\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}};
    \fi
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
      % Draw grid 
      \ifdeveloppath
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.02,ystep=.02] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \draw[red, ultra thick] #2 -- cycle;
      \else
        % Use the path to clip
        \path[clip] #2 -- cycle;
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
      \fi
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

     \clippicture{[width=1.0\textwidth]{some-image}}{(0.359,0.268) -- (0.48,0.73) -- (0.52,0.73) -- (0.64,0.27) -- (0.60,0.27) -- (0.562,0.403) -- (0.43,.403) -- (0.395, 0.268) -- (0.359,0.268)}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

    \tikzset{develop clipping path=false}

\begin{center}
    \clippicture{[width=1.0\textwidth]{some-image}}{(0.359,0.268) -- (0.48,0.73) -- (0.52,0.73) -- (0.64,0.27) -- (0.60,0.27) -- (0.562,0.403) -- (0.43,.403) -- (0.395, 0.268) -- (0.359,0.268)}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: My clipping path is a closed circuit; and so, the output is the outer portion of the capital *A*. How might I complete the extraction of the letter *A* by---clipping out as well---the  appropriate inner portion of the letter *A*?

Thank you.

Comment: `example-image` and `example-image-a` is not the same image. Nowhere do you define the path of the inner triangle of the "A". A clipping path can like a fill path use `nonzero rule` or `even odd rule` (if the option is given to a scope(bug in TikZ)).

Comment: @hpekristiansen Many thanks for pointing out my oversight regarding `example-image` and `example-image-a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the inner triangle of the "A" counter clockwise(using the "nonzero rule") to your path making it:

```
(0.359,0.268) -- (0.48,0.73) -- (0.52,0.73) -- (0.64,0.27) -- (0.60,0.27) -- (0.562,0.403) -- (0.43,.403) -- (0.395, 0.268) -- (0.359,0.268) (0.440,0.438) -- (0.555,0.438) -- (0.498,0.675)  -- (0.44,0.44)
```

[image: An "A" on a gray grid with red outline]
[image: An "A"]

When making a closed path, it is better to use `cycle` instead of repeating the first coordinate. This makes the path:

```
(0.359,0.268) -- (0.48,0.73) -- (0.52,0.73) -- (0.64,0.27) -- (0.60,0.27) -- (0.562,0.403) -- (0.43,.403) -- (0.395, 0.268) -- cycle (0.440,0.438) -- (0.555,0.438) -- (0.498,0.675) -- cycle
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.